# How do I selectively hide a navigation bar using Angular?

Tags: angular, navigation, navigationbar

We want to hide the login bar on the `login` page. The value in the template never changes, and the only page we want to hide the navigation is on the login-page.

The service that is called when the navigation bar should get enabled or disabled.
isAuthenticated.service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable}     from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class isAuthenticatedService{

userLoggedIn : boolean = false;

//call this function when login status changes
changeLoginStatus(status: boolean){
    this.userLoggedIn = status;
    console.log("in changeLoginStatus: ", status);
}

getLoginStatus(){
    return this.userLoggedIn;
}
}
```

app.component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ProfilComponent} from './profil.component';
import {EditProfilComponent} from './editProfil.component';
import { HTTPService } from './http.service';
import {CookieService} from 'angular2-cookie/services/cookies.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {isAuthenticatedService} from './isAuthenticated.service'

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl: './app/main.html',
providers: [HTTPService, CookieService, isAuthenticatedService]
})
export class AppComponent{
constructor(private _httpService: HTTPService, private _cookieService: CookieService, public router: Router, private _isAuthenticatedService: isAuthenticatedService){
    console.log(this.router.url);
}
};
```

Template that is used in app.component to display the navigation.

main.html:

```
<div [hidden]="_isAuthenticatedService.userLoggedIn">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a routerLink="/mainpage">Portal |</a></li>
   <li><a routerLink="/profil">Profil</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Unternehmen</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
 <div class="dropdown" style="float:right;">
<button class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id ="profildd">Profil <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a routerLink="/profil" routerLinkActive="active">Verwalten</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/download" routerLinkActive="active">Organisation</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/" (click)="logout()">Logout</a></li>
    </ul> 
</div>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

The function 'changeLoginStatus(boolean)' is called from the login component if the login was successfull.

**Edit 1: Changed Providers**

moved providers from app.component to app.module.ts

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [ 
BrowserModule,
HttpModule,
FormsModule,
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {path : '', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'mainpage', component: MainPageComponent},
  {path: 'profil', component: ProfilComponent},
  {path: 'editProfil', component: EditProfilComponent},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent}
])

],

 declarations: [ AppComponent, ProfilComponent, EditProfilComponent, LoginComponent, MainPageComponent],
 providers : [
{       provide: XSRFStrategy,
        useValue: new CookieXSRFStrategy('XSRF-Token', 'XSRF-TOKEN')
}, isAuthenticatedService, CookieService, HTTPService],
bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is

```
providers: [HTTPService, CookieService, isAuthenticatedService]
```

This line creates different instance of the service (*per component*) and so you will not have expected outcome.

*you should use singleton service which shares single instance of the service among components where one component changes something in service and other component gets the same update via service*

So for that pupose you should declare your service in `RootModule's` or `AppModule's` `@NgModule decorator` as shown below,

```
@NgModule({
   ...
   providers: [HTTPService, CookieService, isAuthenticatedService]  
   //<<< this will create single instance of services throughout app
  ...
})
```

AND REMOVE `providers:[...]` declaration from `@Component`,

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app/main.html',
    providers: [HTTPService, CookieService, isAuthenticatedService] 
    //<<< providers not required here as it creates different instance per component.

})
```

EDIT 1:
try this also,

```
<div [hidden]="_isAuthenticatedService.getLoginStatus()">
```

Comment: nothing changed. Moved all provider from app.component to app.module (see Edit 1)

Comment: Update should work. Need to also see what you are doing with function. I updated my answer but it represents the same thing

Comment: Tried your edit as well. The result is still the same. What function do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering why such complicated solutions here?  You just need something that checks whether the user is logged in in your Navigation Component like this:

**Navmenu.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
import { AuthService } from '../authguard/auth.service';

@Component({
selector: 'nav-menu',
providers: [Location, { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy }],
templateUrl: './navmenu.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./navmenu.component.css']})

export class NavMenuComponent {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }
  location: Location;
  isActive() {
  return !this.authService.loggedIn();
  }
...
}
```

**navmenu.component.html:**

```
<div class='main-nav' [hidden]="isActive()">
<div class='navbar navbar-inverse'>
...
```

Then, in your top menu bar , have a login/logout 'panel':

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            <a (click)=authService.login() *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()">Log In</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a (click)=authService.logout() *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()">Log Out</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-3'>
        <nav-menu></nav-menu>
...
```